# How do I store data from a text file to then use it within a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

text_file_list = ["question1.txt", "question2.txt", "question3.txt", "question4.txt"]

def user_interface():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.title("Question")
                    
    with open(choice(text_file_list), "r") as f:
            Label(window, text=f.readline()).pack()
                    
    Answer_A = Button(window, text="Answer A").pack(pady=10) 
    Answer_B = Button(window, text="Answer B").pack(pady=10)
    Answer_C = Button(window, text="Answer C").pack(pady=10)
    window.mainloop()

user_interface()
```

The aim of my code is to ask the user a question from a text file and then give them three buttons to chose the answer from. My code currently choses a random question and the buttons are displayed but do not have a function yet.

The correct answers to the questions are within the text file with the question itself. How can I get this answer and use it within my tkinter buttons?

Comment: What is the format of the files? How is the question and answers formatted inside the file?

Comment: The question is just on a notepad file. I've asked the question and given choices of A, B and C for answers on the first line of the text file. The following line I've just put the letter corresponding to the correct answer. For example, Calculate 4x2  A.)12  B.)8  C.)10 (first line) and the second line would just be 'B'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

text_file_list = ["question1.txt", "question2.txt", "question3.txt", "question4.txt"]


def user_interface():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.title("Question")
                    
    with open(choice(text_file_list), "r") as f:
        Label(window, text=f.readline()).pack()
        correct_answer = f.readline()
                    
    answer_label = Label(window)

    def answer_callback(answer):
        if answer == correct_answer:
            answer_label["text"] = "Your answer was correct!"
        else:
            answer_label["text"] = "Your answer was wrong."

    Button(window, text="Answer A", command=lambda: answer_callback("A")).pack(pady=10) 
    Button(window, text="Answer B", command=lambda: answer_callback("B")).pack(pady=10)
    Button(window, text="Answer C", command=lambda: answer_callback("C")).pack(pady=10)
    answer_label.pack()
    window.mainloop()

user_interface()
```

Comment: @LXYSam The answer is meant to be on the second line, as you mentioned in the comment. On your second line, do you have the answer wrapped into quotation marks? If so, try to remove them. If it still doesn't work, in the answer_callback, try to print out answer and correct_answer and send the result

Comment: Its working as intended now thank you. Is there a way of closing the tkinter window once an answer has been chosen? Would I just use destroy() within my button setup?

Comment: @LXYSam Yes you can use window.destroy() within the answer_callback. Maybe it would make sense to close the window only if the correct answer was chosen and after a time delay  (maybe try tkinter's "after" or something). If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it as accepted :)